# Creating javascript objects best practice?

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

While I am practicing my javascript knowledge and wanting it to be as efficient as possible, what way should I go about creating objects and instances of them?

```
var obj1 = {key1: value1, key2: value2, key3: value3};
```

or

```
var obj2 = {

    key1: value1,
    key2: value2,
    key3: value3

};
```

or

```
var obj3 = new Object();
obj3.key1 = value1;
obj3.key2 = value2;
obj3.key3 = value3;
```

Now, I understand they all write an object, but my question concerns the best practice for me to follow.  What do you see most often in .js files, and how should I practice writing them?

Comment: Most style guides recommend [using array and object literals](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#Array_and_Object_literals). That said, this is largely a matter of opinion.

Comment: Using `{ }` is the recommended way over `new` action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's largely a matter of opinion and style.  As @Chris Tavares noted, using the `new Object()` constructor is not recommended.  As for option 1 in your example code, I don't think that it looks as readable as option number two.

My advice to you, however, is not to worry too much about 'proper' styling at this point in your javascript career.  Again, as @Chris says, "do whatever is most readable/maintainable."  I'd like to piggyback onto that and say that as you move forward in your javascript carreer, you're going to read and write a lot of code, and through reading and writing, you are going to get a much better **intuition** for what readable/maintainable look like.  As you get into frameworks and the like, you will also start stronger standards.

All of that said, I think number two is by far the best, as it is the most readable/maintainable.  That is the method that I use most of the time, and that most code that I read uses.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind as I go along with my career.

Answer (score 1):

First and second are identical - the only difference is whitespace, which gets stripped out as part of the language parsing.

Calling `new Object()` isn't recommended - use the literal `{}` instead. Otherwise, do whatever is the most readable/maintainable in the context you're writing the code. Usually this is something that looks like your #2.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to best practice, it's important to note that it is very subjective. That said, if you look around at other people's code, you will certainly start to see patterns emerge, especially in regards to defining objects.

One of my favorite style-guides for JavaScript is the [AirBnB style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript). If you ever have a general question about style, that is a great place to start.

In regards to your question, take a look at the [objects](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#objects) section of the guide. Most people would agree that using object literal syntax `{}` and breaking up each key/value pair on a new line is preferable.

I would always define my objects like so:

```
var obj2 = {
  key1: value1,
  key2: value2,
  key3: value3
};
```

It is definitely important to reiterate that style guides are highly subjective. The most important thing is to find a consistent way of writing code that best conveys your intent (that is, easy to read and understand).

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot and I will disregard writing the new Object() way, as it seems to be time consuming and broken up.  Thanks for the reference to the guide, I'll definitely be using this as I go along.